# Same object inserted twice with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wondering if it's possible (while using entity framework) to insert 2 entities with the same key?

Say we have a model like this:

```
class Foo {
    Bar Bar1 { get; set; }
    Bar Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

Where Bar1 and Bar2 could be the same 'Bar'. For instance:

Say we have a key inside Bar:

```
class Bar {
    int Key { get; set; }
}
```

An instance of the Foo-class could look like:

```
Foo.Bar1.Key == 1
Foo.Bar2.Key == 1
```

Hence they are the same entity.

However, if I try to insert the Foo into the database, it results in entity framework trying to add both Bar1 and Bar2 separately, which then results in an primary key violation.

My question is this:

**Is it possible to tell entity framework to skip adding Bar2 and just to add a reference to Bar1?**

Comment: I think you can declare that `Key` is a primary key using an attribute, although I cannot recall its name.

Comment: If `Bar` had more properties, like a `Name`, and there were two instances of `Bar`, one for `Bar1` and one for `Bar2`, with different `Name`s but the same `Key`, then which name should be saved?

Comment: In this instance it would be the one that's inserted first. What I'm looking for is a way to tell entity framework that if it finds that the primary key already exists, it should add a reference to the already stored entity, instead of trying to insert another one with the same key.

Comment: Why don't u check it dbContext before insertion. Using linq operators. Like ' Contans' or 'Any()'  ??

Comment: Because `Bar` is not necessarily inserted before `Foo`. But gets added when `Foo` is added.

Comment: I recently went through a problem like this. I will suggest that don't do what you are trying to do because ultimately you will have to change it.

Insert is fine and you can give reference to the same key multiple times in Foo table but the problem occurs when you will delete because the database will through a referential integrity exception because you will have the references of the same key at multiple places.